# Can a garbage disposal drain pipe be plumbed directly into a wye fitting?

Tags: plumbing, pvc, garbage-disposal

After trying a few methods to unclog a kitchen sink, I ended up disassembling the plumbing underneath my sink.  After seeing the previous homeowner's handiwork up close, I've decided to replumb a dual basin sink w/ garbage disposal.  However, the waste line for the sink is behind the garbage disposal and is limiting my options.

The attached pictures show a dry fit of my current plan, minus the proper adapter for the disposal to PVC connection:
[image: Side View]

[image: front view]

Are there any issues with this planned layout?  The other basin will drain into the top of the wye fitting, and the wall discharge has a vent through to the roofline.

UPDATE:

After FreeMan's comment highlighting the potential for the wye fitting to be marked noncompliant, I went back to the drawing board and used a sanitary tee fitting with a 90 elbow, cutting down the discharge tube to properly line up with the fitting.  After carefully laying out the plumbing, I glued it together.

I found a threaded P trap at my local hardware store - I would have liked a true cleanout port, but there's not enough room behind the disposal.  This way, the threaded cap can be loosened and the entire pipe assembly to the wall removed for access with an auger if a clog develops.

Thank you to everyone who commented/posted!
[image]

[image]

Comment: very creative ...

Comment: What's your plan for sealing that connection?

Comment: I would think that a reducer bushing would work well there, @Huesmann. This is good, creative thinking, indeed! Though, I'd strongly recommend _against_ what looks to be a glued p-trap. You want a screw together one so you can clean it out easily. If you even need to disassemble this one for cleaning or to recover jewelry, you're cutting the _whole thing_ out and replacing it all - there's zero room to reglue these joints.

Comment: You have clean out means including the fernco.  No need for a "port" in addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need the trap adapter to make the seal, since this is (properly) ahead of the P-trap, not after it *(which we have seen, sadly.)*

If you have nit-picking inspectors, it's an improper use of a wye, since those are supposed to be horizontal, and a vertical would normally use a sanitary tee, but the fact that it's ahead of the trap might give you an out on that front. Practically speaking, it should work fine here.